# Weird PHP While Loop

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've been trying to work this one out in my head for hours and still no luck so I'm resulted to here.

For some reason when the code has the query uncommented the loop will only loop once even tho there are 3 logs in the database if we then comment the query it works as expected.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `savedusers`");
$sth->execute();
while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  $run++;
  foreach($sites as $site){
    $clients = ${CalculateControllerVar($site['site_id'])}->list_clients($site['site_id']);
    foreach($clients as $client){
      if(strtolower($client->mac) == strtolower($row['Mac'])){
        $aps = ${CalculateControllerVar($site['site_id'])}->list_aps($site['site_id'], $client->ap_mac);
        $sth = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE `savedusers` SET `Location` = :loc WHERE `Mac` = :mac");
        $sth->execute(array(':loc' => $aps[0]->name, ':mac' => $row['Mac']));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you determine that it only loop once?

Comment: By echoing the $run after the loop.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are overwriting variable `$sth` in your commented code. Change those lines to:

```
$sth2 = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE `savedusers` SET `Location` = :loc WHERE `Mac` = :mac");
$sth2->execute(array(':loc' => $aps[0]->name, ':mac' => $row['Mac']));
```

and it will work properly.

Comment: OH MY GOD I'm so dumb I've spent hours looking at this. Thanks.